# Set a pandas column to a timezone only datetime object

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, pytz

I'm trying to refactor a piece of code which is very slow. It takes the timezoneId of every row and applies the pytz.timezone() method to transform that into a datetime object, with only the timezone info.

for example, the Dataframe looks like this:
`df = pd.DataFrame([['America/Sao_Paulo'], ['US/Eastern'], ['Europe/Moscow']], index =['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3'])`

I need these strings to be converted to datetime objects.

If I try to use .apply(pytz.timezone) I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'upper'`

And I cannot use the .to_datetime Pandas method with only timezone information.

How would I got about creating a datetime object with only timezone information?

EDIT:

Here's what the code I'm rewriting looks like:

```py
try:
    tz_id = data[-1]['timezone']['timeZoneId']
    self.timezone = pytz.timezone(tz_id)
except:
    self.timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
return self.timezone
```

It only takes one ID per time, which is why it currently works and is so slow.

Comment: What is the value of `US/Eastern` as a `datetime` object?

Comment: just "US/Eastern" as if it were a string. The problem is these items will be passed to functions which only accept datetime objects as inputs, for example datetime .astimezone()

Comment: I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: in general, looking up time zones takes time. [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) might be faster than pytz. Still, a bit hard to guess without knowing more context (this seems to be part of some class?). For a pandas dataframe for example, you could also gain efficiency if you only look up the unique time zones (not for each row).